# Arduino takes too long to upload, avrdude: ser_drain() error (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: arduino, ftdi, avrdude

I'm having trouble uploading basic sample sketches to my arduino Lilypad. It takes a really long time to upload (1-3 minutes) after compiling. The IDE shows that the sketch has been uploaded, however, the console shows nothing. Everytime I plug in my board, the light keeps blinking, but nothing else happens.

After failing to see any sample sketch working, I tried with this simple test, and it still didn't work.

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(1);
}
```

So far I've checked the port, that the right board is selected and I've installed the latest drivers for my FTDI conversor (mini usb to TTL FTDI FT232RL). These are the error mesagges:

```
Arduino:1.8.14 Hourly Build 2020/09/23 10:35 (Mac OS X), Tarjeta:"LilyPad Arduino, ATmega328P"

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfe
```

```
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: Device not configured

avrdude: ser_send(): write error: Device not configured
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: Device not configured
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: Device not configured
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: Device not configured
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

And so on.
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect a **corrupted bootloader** is affecting the communications with your Lillypad (ATMEGA328P). You could try reprogramming the bootloader using another Arduino as ISP connecting it to the pins according to this image:

[image: Lilypad ICSP port]

As it was already reported in [other](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=344549.0) forums, there are some counterfeit boards on the market. If that is not the case, it is not uncommon for the bootloader to get corrupted if the board is mishandled when powered-up or if you *look at it when it's not in the mood* ( :P ).

Try to follow the steps from [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoISP) guide in order to reload the bootloader.

Another option is to use an USBasp like [this](https://www.banggood.com/3_3V-5V-USBASP-USBISP-AVR-Programmer-Downloader-ATMEGA8-ATMEGA128-With-Download-Cable-p-1179967.html?cur_warehouse=CN) and burn the bootloader as it is explained [here](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2011/12/19/burning-arduino-bootloader-with-avr-usbasp/)